# Default chunk length of Android HttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode()?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

In the documentation of [HttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setChunkedStreamingMode(int)), it said if I specify 0 in the parameter, it will use default chunk length, such as:

```
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

What is the exact value of the default chunk length? and what is the unit of the parameter? in bytes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question made me curious so I tested some stuff.

**What is the exact value of the default chunk length?**

I found [here](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) that chunkLength is a [protected variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private) of the HttpURLConnection class, meaning it's only accessible inside the class itself or in a subclass. So I made a subclass of HttpURLConnection and tried to print out the chunkLength

```
class HttpTest extends HttpURLConnection {

    protected HttpTest(URL url) {
        super(url);
        Log.d("CHUNKLENGTH", String.format("%d", this.chunkLength));
        this.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        Log.d("CHUNKLENGTH", String.format("%d", this.chunkLength));
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean usingProxy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Calling it like this

```
try {
    HttpTest test = new HttpTest(new URL("http://www.google.com/"));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

These were the results

[image]

From that, we can conclude that the default value it uses is 1024

---

**what is the unit of the parameter?**

At the link you posted, it is mentioned that

> A small chunk length increases **the number of bytes that must be transmitted** because of the header on every chunk.

I think it's safe to assume you have to give the number of bytes. The default 1024 also fits that criteria